# Apply function to variable size list in R

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of files that group together by day (example list below) and want to read each one into a dataframe and bind them together. I'm currently stuck finding a way to avoid the "manual" `my_files` reference as the `my_files` list could sometimes have more than two days and this would break. Any ideas?

```
my_files <- list(c("file1_day0.txt", "file2_day0.txt"), c("file3_day3.txt", "file4_day3.txt"))

df <- rbind(lapply(my_files[[1]], create_activation_df) %>%
                purrr::reduce(dplyr::left_join, by = c("date",
                                                       "experiment")),
              lapply(my_files[[2]], create_activation_df) %>%
                purrr::reduce(dplyr::left_join, by = c("date",
                                                       "experiment")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another layer of `lapply` is what you need. This is obviously untested with no reproducible example shared, but it should get the point across:

```
df <- bind_rows(
  lapply(my_files, \(x) {
    lapply(x, create_activation_df) %>%
      purrr::reduce(dplyr::left_join, by = c("date", "experiment"))
  }
)
```

Comment: Genius. Thank you. I felt like it was right under my nose, but I was overthinking it.

Comment: Could you explain the `\(x)`, not sure I've seen that before.

Comment: Since R 4.1.0, `\(x)` is shorthand for `function(x)`.